# How to display android text selection indicators handlers

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, flex4.6

the selection indicator isn't shown at the text input field

is there any solution for this problem ?

i am using flash builder 4.5 + flex 
in Android mobile Application

plz help

the selection indicators in this photo

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4mHT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I believe these are for "Android" text areas labels and text inputs, I don't know that the AIR/Flash based components can allow the Android behavior within them without re-writing it.  When you create these components within an AIR application to run on mobile you aren't using the same framework or components so the default behavior won't happen.  You can either re-code up the same behavior within AS3 or you have to switch to actually developing the app as an Android native application (so far as I know but if I'm wrong anyone feel free to point it out as it would be good to know).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not yet supported in Adobe AIR